# how to set lifetime of jwt token in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, jwt, authorization

I have created project in asp.net core 3.1, and I am able to successfully authorized it.

The issue is I want to increase the lifetime of JWT token, I tried all possible ways but still could not get proper help or answer for what I am looking for.

Below is the code in **startup.cs**

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
   {
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        //ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
        ValidIssuer = _configuration.GetSection("BaseUrl").Value,
        ValidAudience = _configuration.GetSection("BaseUrl").Value,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("IssuerSigningKey").Value)),
    };

    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
         OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
         {
             context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
             {
                  context.Response.StatusCode = 499;
                  return Task.CompletedTask;
             });

             if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
             {
                  context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
             }
         return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
  };
});
```

Below is code to **generate JWT token**,

```
string GeneratJwtToken()
{
            var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("IssuerSigningKey").Value));
            var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var claims = new[] { new Claim("Source", "PmpMobileApp") };

            var tokeOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _configuration.GetSection("BaseUrl").Value,
                audience: _configuration.GetSection("BaseUrl").Value,
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(20),
                signingCredentials: signinCredentials
            );
            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokeOptions);
}
```

I had seen refresh token concept, but for refresh token it should return 401 unauthorized error from middleware then I can call refresh token api. But in this it will return 200 success with login page.

Also noticed, token does not expires in local development environment, but expires in production environment in few mins.

Note:- Using same project for web and mobile.

Comment: Since the token content is readable, because it's just base64url encoded, you should debug the token with e.g. [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io), and check the value of the `exp` property. If you hover over it, it shows the human readable datetime. The `ValidateLifetime` option basically just checks if this given datetime is past; so if the `exp` datetime contains the expected value, the token shouldn't be treated as expired after a few minutes (and the issue might be something else).

Answer (score 0):

You have set it to expire after 20 seconds in your GeneratJwtToken() method:

```
 expires: DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(20)
```

Comment: I did it in the same way, but it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean the same way? What I wrote is what you posted. You set it to expire after 20 seconds. You said you want to increase the lifetime. If for example you want it to last 1 day, you have to write DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).

Comment: If I change it to even DateTime.Now.AddYears(1), then also it is expiring after few mins.

Answer (score 0):

use the property Expires in cookieOption.

```
var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7) 
            };
```

Works perfectly!